# How to change 2 column values with a case statement in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am looking to find out how I can change values in 2 columns based on a case when statement.

An example of the table data is below (live data has around 60 columns that I have bring in but only this column:

```
QUEUE | NOTES
12345 | Lorem 
12345 | ipsum
45678 | dolor
78901 | sit
90123 | amet
```

Now I have written the following query that gives me the first part:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN SUBSTR (QUEUE, 1, 2) = '12'
  THEN 'Abandoned'
  ELSE QUEUE
  END AS QUEUE,
  NOTES
FROM
  TABLE_1
;
```

The second step that I need to undertake is based on the first case statement. If the queue field has the queue abandoned then I need to replace the note field with text saying 'Queue Amended by User AN 29.09.16' but I am not sure how I go about doing this.

I am guessing I could write it in a sub select query but again I don't know how I target if one column value equals something then replace another columns values. Also would like to know if its possible to write it all within one case statement...

If somebody could please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Case expression, not case statement. (It returns a value.)

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE Expression for Note column as well

```
SELECT
  CASE
     WHEN SUBSTR (QUEUE, 1, 2) = '12'
     THEN 'Abandoned'
     ELSE QUEUE
  END AS QUEUE,
  CASE
     WHEN SUBSTR (QUEUE, 1, 2) = '12'
     THEN 'Queue Amended by User AN 29.09.16'
     ELSE NOTES
  END  AS Notes
FROM
TABLE_1
```

Comment: Thanks Jaydip, just to clarify would that overwrite the existing note in the notes field with 'Queue Amended by User AN 29.09.16' or will it add another column with a Notes Field?

Comment: When queue is abandoned then only then it replace Note with given string ow it will gives Notes whatever content in it in same column

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not actually want to update the underlying table_1 but only present the results then you just need to repeat the case statement for the second column:

```
SELECT
  (CASE
    WHEN SUBSTR (QUEUE, 1, 2) = '12'
  THEN 'Abandoned'
  ELSE QUEUE
  END) AS QUEUE,

  (CASE
    WHEN SUBSTR (QUEUE, 1, 2) = '12'
  THEN 'Queue Amended by User ' ||user ||' '|| to_char(sysdate, 'DD.MM.RRRR')
  ELSE NOTES
  END) AS NOTES
FROM table_1
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I would have to go down the route of updating the table as I will need to ensure that if anyone else uses the table then this information is readily available. Also I tried Jaydip's query which would work fine but as already have a notes field as I have a select * then shows column ambiguously defined (as original notes field) so would have to type every column name bar the original notes for it to work...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table called `table_1` with columns `queue` and `notes` with the current values in your sample input, and you must UPDATE the table as you described, it's easy (and you don't need a "case" expression or two, all you need is a WHERE filter):

```
update table_1
   set queue = 'Abandoned',
       notes = 'Queue Amended by User AN 09.29.16'
where  queue like '12%'
;
```

(Or the value for NOTES can be concatenated with variables for User and/or Date as E. Ninis has shown in his/her solution.) Note that the "like" condition will allow Oracle to use an index you may have on the `queue` column; using `substr()` on it will not.